# Php header location redirect not working

Tags: php

No idea why this is not working. Here is the code:

```
if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
{
    header('Location: page1.php');
    echo $_POST['cancel'];
}
```

Instead of redirecting the page, this output's `cancel` to the webpage. It skipped over the redirect. Why? How can I fix this? page1.php is a real page located in the same folder as the current page. The above code is the very first lines of the php file. Nothing before it. Nothing. Not even whitespace.

Comment: Don't echo anything afterwards; do an `exit()` to terminate the script. (You shouldn't output anything after having issued that header)

Comment: It's because you've already sent data to the browser in this context and therefore the `headers have been sent`. Turn on your `error_reporting` to get this answer in the future.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That isn't the source of the problem.  You can echo anything you want afterwards... it just doesn't make any sense because the browser won't show it, so you're just wasting bytes.

Comment: @JohnS It's not possible to help you since you don't show us any debugging output.  What do you see when you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 using echo is fine, I doubt the condition isn't sufficed

Comment: @Pekka웃 I do not see any reasons, why it shouldn't work, if OP sends data afterwards. It doesn't matter. What matters, that if OP sends data *before*.

Comment: Error reporting is on. No errors. If I take the echo statement out, then it continues with the rest of the page anyways. I included the echo statement to show the if statement is executing.

Comment: var_dump shows value is 'cancel' of type string

Comment: @JohnS did you sent any data to client (spaces included) before `header(...)` ?

Comment: @Mr. Alien, HAL9000 - true.

Comment: No. No data sent to client. None. <?php is the only preceding line to the above code. No whitespace. Not one space. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use absolute URL path to page?

Comment: @JohnS try this `header('Location: ABSOLUTE_URL_HERE', true, 302);`

Comment: I just tried the absolute url. h t t p : / / l o c a l h o s t/ etc. (without the spaces). It still echo's out the statements and does not redirect.

Comment: @JohnS Could you, please, provide entire script? Looks like those lines is not the ones, that produces an issue, that you encountering.

Comment: Does sessions have any affect on this issue? I start the session AFTER the above code, just incase the session affects the header information.

Comment: @JohnS yes, bring session at the very top of the page

Comment: I had multiple header(location:example.php); statements on the same page. I'm not sure why this was an issue exactly, but this is the culprit.

Comment: Try adding ob_start(); at the top of the code i.e. before the include statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pekka answered my question in the comments. He didn't post an answer, so I am now. Use the `exit()` method after the header redirect. For some reason the rest of the code of the page continues to execute after the header() method redirect. When the rest of the code executes, the echo statement is outputted to the page. And you can't redirect using the header function after you output to the page. To avoid rest of the code from executing, use `exit()`. Thanks Pekka.

UPDATE: When using the web browser Internet Explorer, I have noticed that $_POST['cancel'] is not reliable. I am not exactly sure why this is, but I suspect IE posts additional variables on a form submit, specifically the variable 'cancel' is posted. I solved this by using a variable name other than 'cancel'. The combination of using exit() and a unique variable name is working for me.

Answer (score 26):

This is likely a problem generated by the headers being already sent.

### Why

This occurs if you have echoed anything before deciding to redirect. If so, then the initial (default) headers have been sent and the new headers cannot replace something that's already in the output buffer getting ready to be sent to the browser.

Sometimes it's not even necessary to have echoed something yourself:

- if an error is being outputted to the browser it's also considered content so the headers must be sent before the error information;
- if one of your files is encoded in one format (let's say ISO-8859-1) and another is encoded in another (let's say UTF-8 with BOM) the incompatibility between the two encodings may result in a few characters being outputted;

### Let's check

To test if this is the case you have to enable error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and set the errors to be displayed `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` after which you will likely see a warning referring to the headers being already sent.

### Let's fix

Fixing this kinds of errors:

- writing your redirect logic somewhere in the code before anything is outputted;
- using output buffers to trap any outgoing info and only release it at some point when you know all redirect attempts have been run;
- Using a proper MVC framework they already solve it;

### More

MVC solves it both functionally by ensuring that the logic is in the controller and the controller triggers the display/rendering of a view only at the end of the controllers. This means you can decide to do a redirect somewhere within the action but not withing the view.

Answer (score 23):

I have experienced that kind of issue before and now I'm not using `header('Location: pageExample.php');` anymore, instead I'm using javascript's `document.location`.

Change your:

```
header('Location: page1.php');
```

To something like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'page1.php'; </script>";
```

And what is the purpose of `echo $_POST['cancel'];` by the way?, just delete that line if what you want is just the redirection. I've been using that `<script>` every time and it doesn't fail me. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Use `@obstart` or try to use `Java Script`

put your `obstart();` into your top of the page

```
if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
{
    header('Location: page1.php');
    exit();
}
```

---

If you use `Javascript` Use  `window.location.href`

window.location.href example:

```
 if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'page1.php';</script>"
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: A header redirect will only send the HTTP headers specifying the new URL you have been redirected to. Using JS is a workaround -- it means having to receive/parse/run a page (HTTP headers + some content) and then the JavaScript will trigger a new request for which to receive/parse/run another page.

Answer (score 11):

I had also the similar issue in godaddy hosting.
But after putting ob_start(); at the beginning of the php page from where page was redirecting, it was working fine.

Please find the example of the fix:

fileName:**index.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
...
header('Location: page1.php');
...
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem... 
solved by adding `ob_start();` and  `ob_end_flush();`
...

```
<?php 
ob_start();


require 'engine/vishnuHTML.class.php';
require 'engine/admin/login.class.php';

$html=new vishnuHTML();
 (!isset($_SESSION))?session_start():"";

/* blah bla Code
...........
...........
 */

</div>
</div>
<?php
}



ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Think of ob_start() as saying "Start remembering everything that would normally be outputted, but don't quite do anything with it yet."

ob_end_clean() or ob_flush(), which either stops saving things and discards whatever was saved, or stops saving and outputs it all at once, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

For me also it was not working. Then i try with javascript inside php like

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='index.php'; </script>";
```

This will definitely working.

Comment: sometimes it won't work, you have to put ob_start/end. see my post, you will get something else.

Answer (score 4):

Neer to specify exit code here so php not execute further

```
if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
{
    header('Location: page1.php');        
    exit(0); // require to exit here 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

> ob_start();

at the top of the code i.e. before the include statement.

Comment: You need to explain ***why?***

Comment: Add ob_start(); top of you page, like after <php ob_start(); echo 'html, head, etc'; ?>

Answer (score 3):

Make Sure that you don't leave a space before `<?php` when you start `<?php` tag at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful with whitespace and other stuff that may affect the "output" already done. I certainly know this but still suffered from the same problem. My whole "Admin.php"-file had some spaces after the closing php-tag ?> down the bottom on the last row :)

Easily discovered by adding...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

...which told me which line of code that generated the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Add `@ob_start()` function in top of the page,

```
if ((isset($_POST['cancel'])) && ($_POST['cancel'] == 'cancel'))
{
    header('Location: page1.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on')
{

    $self = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    ?>

     <script type='text/javascript'>
     window.location.href = 'http://<?php echo $self ?>';
     </script>"
     <?php

     exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put < ?php tag on the top of your file (starting on frist line of document)

not:

```
--- Blank space or something ---
<?php
```

but:

```
<?php
..your code
header('Location: page1.php');
...
```

Comment: Are you kidding? I copied the following from my original post, “The above code is the very first lines of the php file. Nothing before it. Nothing. Not even whitespace.” It looks like I didn’t include the opening php tag in my code above, but trust me that there’s no whitespace before the opening php tag. The exit function after the redirect resolved this. I don’t think the redirect would work if there was any output, with or without the exit function.

Comment: in my website exit() didn't work but also worked this: "<?php "ob_start(); ..." at the beginning and "...ob_end_flush(); ?>" at the end of document.