# Page not getting redirected php

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I have passed some values from a page to another using ajax with request method post. But there is one condition that f some one is directly accessing the url, it should be redirected to some other page. Problem is that its not getting redirected **(In else condition in img.php)** . Can any one tell me what mistake I am committing?

Thanks in advance.

Code:-

imageupload.php:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    saveImgfunc();
});

function saveImgfunc(){
    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('saveImg'));
    var file = document.getElementById('imgVid').files[0];
    if (file) {   
        form.append('imgVid', file);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'core/img.php',
        data : form,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false
    }).success(function(data){
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

img.php:

```
<?php
require '../core.php';
$qry = new ProcessQuery('localhost', 'root', '', 'mkart');

$uid = 6;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
//Some code here
}
else{
    header("Location : ../core.php");
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);exit;` before `if` and see what you are getting.

Comment: When coming from iageupload.php, its giving - string(4) "POST". On direct access of url its lank. @sgtBOSE

Comment: One point noted: Its going even inside else loop.

Answer (score 3):

See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21229246/682754

There's a good chance that you may have some whitespace before you use the header function? Perhaps in the form of a hidden error/warning.

Try the following at the top of your PHP code in img.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

Would advise removing that once you've found your issue

Comment: @VineetMishra this post is about headers already sent. Follow the link, and do the @ob_start() before saying this won't work./

Answer (score 1):

It works for me removing the whitespace between `Location` and `:`

```
header("Location: ../core.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Error found. In the core.php thre is one code which stopping the further execution of code. Its specially coded for uid = 6. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad you found the issue, I would definitely look into a tool called xdebug if you don't know about it already. It will help you identify the flow through your code and you can be 100% sure of the flow without printing echos/var_dump/exits etc. We've all been there but xdebug is an amazing thing to have, trust me

Answer (score 0):

Dont use   `header("Location : ../core.php");`  some time it gives error or not working properly so use javascript redirection

like

```
?>
 <script>window.location='../core.php';</script>
<?php
```