# PHP form not redirecting, going to form post

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

im using this contact form below. When I was running it on my local machine it was working. But on my server if the form fails it does the right thing and goes to fail.php but when all the fields are filled it goes to send_contact2.php after clicking send instead of success.php

This is the send_contact2.php

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])
    || empty($_POST['number'])
    || empty($_POST['email'])
    || empty($_POST['messagearea'])
){
    header('Location: fail.php');
}

else {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $messagearea = $_POST['messagearea'];

    $to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = "Website Message: Contact form";
    $message = '$messagearea';
    $headers = "From: WebsiteMessage";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header("Location: success.php");

}
?>
```

This is my form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact2.php">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"/> <br/>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email"/> <br/>
    <input name="number" type="tel" placeholder="Your Number"/> <br />
    <textarea name="messagearea" cols="" rows="" id="messagearea" placeholder="Your Message"/></textarea> <br/>

    <input name="sumbit" type="submit" value="SEND" id="button2" />
</form>
```

I have this setting in my cPanel

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check your error log for any errors...is the email being sent when the form submission proceeds without failing?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob no error and the email is not sending, im just using some standard shared hosting. but theres nothing in the error docs

Comment: If email is not sending are you sure the script is ever reaching the else block at all? Try placing die('QA'); inside the else block and then submit the form successfully and see if the string QA gets output on the screen

Comment: @SamJones var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) and see what that says

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yeah QA is showing

Comment: WHere did you place it? Above the mail() function or below? If above, try placing it right below the mail() function and if QA not output then mail() is definitely failing

Comment: above, straight after the else @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: after i get the fail, something wrong in the mail im guessing then @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: Try commenting out line with mail() and see if your script redirects properly to success.php

Comment: yeah goes to success when mail is commented out @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: `'$messagearea'` is wrong anyways, even if the email was sending. `'`-quoted strings do NOT interpolate variables.

Comment: @Marc B you're right message would just be the literal string $messagearea

Comment: Could mail server be down?

Comment: that was my bad yeah but still erroring when i remove quote @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: I can log onto the mail, im thinking it must be something wrong with the server as it worked on mamp

Comment: why send them to a fail page as a means of field validation? why don't you use jquery/javascript to catch the error and alert the user on the same page?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob put a screenshot of my mail setting in my control panel.

Comment: @luke_mclachlan I will do, doesn't solve the mail() problem

Comment: Was a Setting in my hosting!!! sorry for wasting time and thank you @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob for your help debugging

Answer (score 0):

if the page stay on send_contact2.php it is because,  header("Location: success.php") do not redirect. read this post, it could help. [Php header location redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226166/php-header-location-redirect-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion PHP must be outputing some text (char, error or warning?) or you have used a char before `<?php` in your send_contact2.php file. That's why header is not working. Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

Comment: was a php setting on my hosting with the mail server, i'll put it as the answer when i'm allowed to. cheers tho

Answer (score 0):

OP here, managed to sort it in the end

Was a mail server issue, so if anyone in the future gets this problem check your php settings on your hosting and make sure it allows mail() and make sure you set up an email address where you're sending the email to on your server.

thanks to everyone that helped me debug